# I have java program that is trying to connect to a postgres database running on my local machine

Tags: postgresql

I get the following error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
here is what my pg_hba.conf loooks like

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Also I have successfully logged in from the command line using the user postgres

I am using pgAdmin 4 on a MAC.